# Converting a string of Perl code to BASH code

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed, perl

I have this string of Perl code (*which i didn't  write*) that it would be awesome if is converted to BASH code:

```
perl -pe '$j=0; while ( s{.{$j}\K(\d+):}{/} ) {$j += $1+1}'
```

**By using it in terminal:**

```
echo "9:Documents6:users111:User1:Jason" | perl -pe '$j=0; while ( s{.{$j}\K(\d+):}{/} ) {$j += $1+1}'
```

**It results:**

```
/Documents/users1/User1:Jason
```

**Another example:**

```
echo "9:Documents6:users111:User1:Jason
8:Docs for5:user85:User7" | perl -pe '$j=0; while ( s{.{$j}\K(\d+):}{/} ) {$j += $1+1}'
```

**It results:**

```
/Documents/users1/User1:Jason
/Docs for/user8/User7
```

The example of folders names and filename plus the numbers with the colon of the text string may differ, the Perl code will only work with text strings that starts with a number (any number) with colon which is followed by another number with colon **according to the previous one**, **please keep that in mind before trying.**

If you know Perl you know exactly what it does which implies what is must to be done.

**What if is possible to do:** To convert the Perl code to **BASH** alongside with **GNU SED** and maybe combined also with wc.

If is possible only with BASH then even better.

**In worse case scenario:** IF (*that's a big if!*) is not possible with GNU SED then AWK will be used instead assuming that there is no way possible doing it with GNU SED or just BASH, **please keep in mind that i don't care about the simplicity** or any other type of programming language.

**The general idea:**
[image]